# Distribution list messages should get into focused tab

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, distribution, mail-rule

I'm getting messages from a distribution list that people are sending to, it's going into the other tab in outlook.
When I'm trying to set it should get moved automatically to focused, it only gives me the option to move messages from the sender, nor from the distribution list email address.

Answer (score 0):

In exchange side, you could configure mail flow rule to direct email messages to the Focused view for all your users, the rule look like this:
[image]

For more details: [Use the UI to create a transport rule to direct email messages to the Focused view for all your users](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/setup/configure-focused-inbox?view=o365-worldwide#use-the-ui-to-create-a-transport-rule-to-direct-email-messages-to-the-focused-view-for-all-your-users)

In outlook side, according to my research and testing results in my lab, there seems no way to move mails sent to distribution list to focused folder, It can only move emails to the focused folder based on the sender, not based on the recipients.

But you could create a specific folder to receive distribution list mails, the inbox rule look like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your advise.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but the above only helps when you want to apply this rule for anyone with the DL domain name, my question is t apply this rule only for one person.

Comment: It seems cannot achieve your goal:(